# Cordova CaptureVideo - Empty snapshot

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I got this error very time I access to my video camera:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

This are my plugins:

- cordova-labs-local-webserver 2.3.1 "CordovaLocalWebServer"
- cordova-labs-wkwebview-engine-localhost 0.4.0 "Cordova WKWebView Engine with http server (localhost) support"
- cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.0 "Camera"
- cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
- cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
- cordova-plugin-file 4.1.0 "File"
- cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.0 "File Transfer"
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
- cordova-plugin-media 2.1.0 "Media"
- cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.2.0 "Capture"
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.1.1-dev "Splashscreen"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.0.0 "StatusBar"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
- cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.0.1 "Cordova WKWebView Engine"

I'm running iOS9.2 & cordova platform iOS@4.0.1

My code:

```
scope.clip = '';
$scope.record = function(){
  var options = { limit: 1, duration: 8 };
$cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData) {
    Videos.saveVideo(videoData).success(function(data) {
      $scope.clip = data;
      $scope.$apply();
    }).error(function(data) {
      console.log('ERROR: ' + data);
    });
  });
```